# h.264 mp4 video doesn't play on iPad

Tags: mediaelement.js

We are having an issue with mediaelement.js being used in YooTheme's Zoo Media element. We've encoded all our videos to be h.264 mp4s (320x240, 768 bit rate, 25fps), AAC audio(128 bit rate, 44100 sample rate, 2 audio channel, A/V sync basic). The videos are playing in all desktop browsers and even on the iPhone, but will not play on an iPad - we just see the spinning circle. The iPad we are using to test has had the latest updates applied. You can use this url as an example:

http://smoothchords.com/index.php/free-items/item/another-blessing-2?category_id=35

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. At first I thought it was an encoding problem. But then I found the important hint at github:

[hint for usage of mediaelement.js on iOS at github](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/#3-run-startup-script)

The startup script may not be placed in the head tag. After putting it inside the body tag it worked just fine.

P.S.: I checked your site and saw that it worked fine there, so I guess you figured this out yourself. But I thought this answer might help anyone else with this problem.